# Should web sites that use windows authentication require users to login to the web site?

Tags: asp.net, security, web

This may be a dumb question, but why would an internal corporate web app that uses Windows Authentication ask for my Windows credentials before authorizing me to use the functionality in the web app? I would think that if it were using Windows Authentication that the web app should be able to determine my identity based on how I logged onto the domain and authorize me accordingly.

The only reason that I can think of why a website would require me to log into the site using my Windows credentials is if the site really uses forms authentication, for example, and verifies your credentials against a table that is fed from the Active Directory.

Should web sites that use windows authentication require users to login to the web site? It seems like this is an unneccesary step.

Comment: Depends on the browser. IE will automatically negotiate the credential sending, Chrome and Firefox typically will not and they will pop up a dialog requesting your credentials. I believe Firefox can be configured to automatically send your currently active credentials (like IE does). Not sure about Chrome.

Comment: I would say allow but don't require - think of how (for example) sharepoint does it.  You're automagically logged in with your domain creds, but the option is given to log in as someone else - at which point you can provide a different set of credentials.  I guess an argument could be made "make sure the user is that user" in case they didn't lock their machine or whatever, but that could be blamed on AD policy and/or the user as well.

Comment: Actually, for IE it depends on your settings. Go to Internet Options, Security, select the zone you're in, click Custom level, scroll to the bottom. There's different settings for automatically logging you in or prompting you. But I've noticed that even though mine is set to automatically do it, it doesn't always seem to work for some of our Intranet sites.